# Lost passport two weeks ago deboarding in UK

Tags: visas, passports, uk-residents, moroccan-citizens, expired

My wife and I flew from Marrakech to London Gatwick on the easyJet airline and we got to Gatwick and then realised that my expired Moroccan passport containing my I.L.R stamp inside along with my national identity cards had fallen out of the carry on bag upon leaving the plane, we had not even left the airport and started to ask for help in getting to report the situation to someone, but we were told to call easyJet customer service!! Long story short it has been 2weeks and still nobody has contacted us nor have we had any information about the whereabouts of the documents!! Anyone have any idea how to get this sorted??

Comment: I would start with the airport's lost and found department.  But if it's been two weeks and there's no sign of the documents, I would assume the worst, get them all reported lost/cancelled (this will probably require a police report) and start working on replacements.

Comment: I'd prehaps call EasyJet's customer service first again, and make it very clear that you need to file a police report, probably against the airline, as it was the place the passport disappeared. See if you can get escalated to someone who might be able to give you information about where it might end up or get someone to properly look through their lost and found (obviously while being polite). Something like "Oh, my passport went missing on one of your flights, and I've been advised to file a police report against the airline. Do you think someone could have one last check before I do so?"

Answer (score 28):

The rule in most countries is to report a lost passport to the police services and your embassy in the 24 hours after the loss. You haven't done this but should do **AS SOON AS POSSIBLE**

Now, for Morocco, you are required to certify that police report with the embassy ([Consular site of Morocco](https://www.consulat.ma/en/case-loss-receipt-request-id)).

This attracts a [fee](https://www.consulat.ma/en/node/5225) of `110 MAD` (~`8.5 GBP` at time of writing).

After getting it certified, apply for both your *Carte nationale d'identité electronique* (CNIE, national electronic identity card) (fee: `105 MAD` (~`8 GBP`)) and passports (fee: `1080 MAD` (~`84 GBP`)).

For the [CNIE](https://www.consulat.ma/en/renewal-id) the following pieces are needed :

> > In the event of deterioration, lost or stolen documents:
>
> - A declaration must be deposited to the agent in charge of CNIE;
> - A certificate of consular registration, indicating the current address of the person concerned;
> - Two recent identity photographs of face, in colour, on a white background, with 3.5 cm x 4.5 cm format.
> - (Uncovered face and without dark glasses).

**The CNIE / or the reciept of the applicatation is required to get a passport**

---

If you have lost your expired passport, you won't need the below part, but still keeping it for reference, you definitely **will** need to get new CNIEs as it is mandatory for Moroccans to have one at all time, and **especially** get a BRP

For the [passport](https://www.consulat.ma/en/delivery-biometric-passport#attachements1) :

> > The case of an adult person
>
> - Updated consular registration;
> - A valid CNIE(original + photocopy) or a photocopy of the receipt of application for the delivery or renewal of the CNIE.
> - In the event of submitting the CNIE application receipt, the interested party must also provide a birth certificate or an integral
>   copy of the birth certificate less than 6 months old;
> - Two identical and recent passport photographs on white background or light blue background of format 35 mm X 45 mm;

---

The ILR stamp is a bit more of an issue since it may take 6 months, not withstanding that you need the new passport, to get a new Biometric Residence Permit, as the UK doesn't issue ILR stamps anymore.

Apply again **ASAP** (see [site](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/replace-visa-brp)) and make sure **not** to leave the UK or you will [need](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/indefinite-leave-to-remain-in-the-uk) to reapply for a visa before being able to reenter.

Comment: What's a "CIE"?

Comment: @FreeMan: I suspect they're discussing the [Electronic Identity Card](https://www.cartaidentita.interno.gov.it/en/operators/electronic-verification-with-cie/), aka the Carta di Identita Elettronica.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Indeed, but not the Italian one, the Moroccan Carte d'identité Electronique

Comment: The OP stated they had lost their *expired* passport. Presumably they already have a new passport or they would not have been able to fly.

Comment: @Doc Thanks, missed that, editing